# GPS data -> MySQL -> Android sorted ListView

Tags: android, mysql, sorting, gps

I'm programming an Android app that shows data from MySQL database via ListView with some sorting:
1) Items that are *closer to android phone by GPS* are shown firstly

If there are 2 or more items *with equal distance*, second sorting parameter applies - *time*.

2) Items that are closer in time are showm firstly.

Here is a scheme of the process that I guess to implement:

[image: app - nysql connection scheme; table]

My idea is to get all needed rows into Array, then make some PHP manipulations with it and then pull sorted Array to the phone.
(as shown on the image above)

So please advice me what will be the proper way? 
Maybe there is easier method for this functionality?

Or maybe I should do all the sortings exactly in the Android app when programming ListView, getting only standard "SELECT *" array from the database? Then, is there an opportunity to create a ListView with sorting based on calculated values?

Comment: nota : positions are floats, so equal distance is never going to happen

Comment: computation of distance (as the crow flies, of course, not by road) requires some functions that may be available in mysql, in which case, your query can save you a lot of sorting on the phone, especially if you have a lot of data

Comment: You can do sorting on Android, you can create a bean with fields and implement Comparable interface which will allow you to sort the array which you can pass to ListView adapter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).